# Why doesn't elementary OS include screensaver by default?

Tags: development

What made the developer's team to decide not to have a screensaver option on the elementary OS settings?

Comment: I won't add this as an answer because it's really just my opinion on the matter, but screensavers kinda... Don't fit in well. Currently, most screensaver configurations and configurators are a bit janky, and elementaryOS doesn't seem like the kind of distro that would benefit from the current state of screensavers on Linux.

Comment: I am a recovering Windows user.  I feel your pain about no screensaver, but it was a tool that peaked in the CRT days.  I miss my flying toasters.   On the other hand, it would make a great Agile Info Radiator.

Answer (score 4):

Not being one of the devs I can't really answer for them, but I suspect the reason is that screensavers are somewhat obsolete.

Unless you have a really old CRT display it is far better to allow the power saver to kick in instead. That saves the screen better than any screensaver and it saves energy.

There is nothing stopping you from apt installing the screensavers if you really want them though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why eOS doesn't include a screensaver, but personally, I've never used them. They were designed to prevent burn-in on older monitors, so they're now obsolete. More importantly, I always felt that turning off the display was more practical as it prevented burn-in (on older monitors) and saved power.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Daniel Foré, the founder of elementary, on screensavers (see this bug):

I think the general consensus, last time it was discussed, was that it was better to just turn the display off.

As stated before, the periodic table has nothing to do with our brand.

I'm leaning towards this being a won't fix. Screensavers are kind of an outdated concept, IMO